# Distributed by Clause in HIVE

Tags: hadoop, optimization, hive

I have table of with huge data like 100TB.

When I am querying the table I used distributed by clause on particular column (say x).

The table contains 200 distinct or unique values of X.

So When I queried the table with distributed by clause on X the maximum reducers should be 200. But I am seeing it is utilizing MAX reducers i.e. 999

Let me explain with example

Suppose the description of the **emp_table** is as fallows with **3 columns.**

**1.emp_name**

**2. emp_ID**

**3.Group_ID**

```
   and Group_ID has **200 distinct** values
```

Now I want to query the table

**select * from emp_table distributed by Group_ID**;

This Query should use 200 Reducers as per distributed clause. But I am seeing 999 reducers getting utilized.

I am doing it as part optimization. So how can I make sure it should be utilize 200 reducers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The number of reducers in Hive is decided by either two properties.

- hive.exec.reducers.bytes.per.reducer  - The default value is 1GB, This makes hive to create one reducer for each 1GB of input table's size.
- mapred.reduce.tasks - takes an intger value, and those many reducers will be prepared for the job.

The distribute by clause doesn't have any role in deciding the number of reducers, all its work is to distribute/partition the key value from mappers to prepared reducers based on the column given in the clause.

Consider setting the mapred.reduce.tasks as 200, and the distribute by will take care of partitioning the key values to the 200 reducers in even manner.

Comment: @Vamsi Jonnadula, is the answer helpful to you to get clarification?, if not let me know..

Answer (score 0):

The reduce number of hive depends on the size of your input file.But if the output of the mapper contains only 200 groups.Then I guess most of the reduce job will recieve nothing.
If you really want to control the reduce number.`set mapred.reduce.tasks` will help.